# How to validate video upload file size

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, validation

I need to validate video upload size limit in CodeIgniter (on the server side).

I want to validate this by array:

```
array('field' => 'd_video',
    'label' => 'Doctor Video',
    'rules' => 'required|file_allowed_type[media]|upload_max_filesize[3072]')
```

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter's [File Uploading Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CI Document](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) should be like following:

```
$config['upload_path']   = '/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mpeg|avi|wmv';
$config['max_size']      = '2048'; // File Size in KB

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('d_video'))
{
   // Upload Success
}
else
{
   echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```